# Linear Transformation - column of zero's vs row of zeros

Tags: linear-algebra

This is two questions : Let A be an  m by n matrix,

What is the totality of what can be said about the transformation T(x) if A has a row of zeroes ? My answers are : 1) there exists a vector in Rm that cannot be mapped into by T. 2) there exists a free variable   3) T(x) is not 'onto'..4) T(x) = 0 has multiple solutions 5) The columns of A are not linearly independent   6) The columns of A do not span Rm  ...anything else ?

Then a similar question: what can be said about the transformation (or matrix) if there is a column of zeros ?

Thanks for any replies/

Comment: This isn't a HW question; I picked up a Linear Algebra book and am reading it and want to make sure I have a clear view of the first chapter before moving on.. I gave my thoughts on what I think in the case of a row of zeroes....   I will submit what I think if there exisys a column of zeroes.  Can you add or correct my  thoughts regarding a row of zeros ?

Comment: will do .   Can you comment on the row of zeroes ?  do you have anything to add or correct ?

Comment: For answers 4) and 5): $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ is a $2\times 1$ matrix with a row of zeros, and its column is linearly independent.

Comment: yeah....I agree with 2x1 matrix. comment....so scratch 4 and 5 for the moment.   I don't know enough about the subject  to know whether my  list of answers will be   different depending upon whether m=n or is less than n or is greater than n.      (Jean, I don't know what MCQ is)

Comment: I'll submit revised answers later today hopefully.   Gotta go to work

Comment: New thoughts : Given  transformation T and matrix A (m by n). Assume that there is no column of zero's and 1+ rows of zeroes .  Consider the case where m is greater or equal to n.  Determine if the rows span Rn. If yes,  then my conjecture is that there is no free variable and that Ax=0 only has the trivial solution. If no, then I think that there will always be a free variable and Ax=0 has multiple solutions. In both cases the row of 0's has it that the columns will not span A, hence not onto    When m is strictly less than n there will always be a free variable..

Comment: Thus, maybe it's not really important whether m is greater than or less than or equal to n, but more important to consider the span of the rows ( when you have a row of zeros in the matrix)...I'll thinlk about a column  of zeros next, and will see if any comments on the above are offered.  Thanks

Comment: so to summarize my conjecture :  If T is a transformation from Rn to Rm and  If the  rows of  the matrix (m by n) which contains at least one row of zeros span Rn, then Ax=0 only has the trivial solution

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4692211/edit) to include your new thoughts.